# How to align a label in Qt Designer without cutting the label content?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm trying to create a widget that will act as a navigation bar. It is formed by some buttons that are separated by arrows.

[image: 3 buttons separated by arrows]

I'm trying to replicate this picture in Qt Designer using labels with the arrow character → . The problem is that this character is bigger than it seems so when I resize the container, the lower part of the arrow disappears.

[image: 2 buttons separated by a vertical layout that contains a label with an arrow character written in it. The arrow is partially rendered, the lower part of the arrow is cut.]

I have tried to use the vertical layout using a vertical spacer to align the arrow character as the same height as the buttons but the character was cut anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your example by using just the standard settings.
I added two buttons and a label to the horizontalLayout and set the label font size to 55. I also set the text alignment to horizontal center and vertical center.

You will always have more space at the top cause this is the content of the ascii char.

Maybe it's better to use a simple icon?

[image]

EDIT:

You can also add a label or a button with a pixmap/icon which is resizeing with the window:

[image]

Comment: That's the same I have, the problem is that if you squeeze the grid layout or container that wraps everything, the arrow disappears. Can you elaborate on the icon solution?

Comment: That's because your font size didn't resize with your window.

Just add a label or a button with pixamp/icon on it and let them resize with the window. Watch the edited answer.

Comment: I have used another character with less invisible space "➤" that gets a pretty decent result too.